# Boolean comparison treatment by PHP - explanation?

Tags: php, comparison, boolean

I've come across something that intrigued me and I just want to know how to explain why it's happening.

```
$var = true;
if($var == 'X'){
  echo 'pass';
}
```

The above code will trigger 'pass'... why? If i use `$var === 'x'` it'll behave as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 5):

A non-empty string will always evaluate to `TRUE` See [PHP's documentation on boolean evaluation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).  As you have discovered, you must use `===` for strict type comparison to test whether the string `'X'` is identical to the boolean `TRUE`.

```
'X' == TRUE  // TRUE
'' == TRUE   // FALSE
'X' === TRUE // FALSE
```

Comment: +1, One of the many gotchas of a loosely typed language.  @rocksfrow, if you want to check type as well, use `===` instead.

Comment: That makes perfect sense> Thank you!

Comment: Brad, yep... as said in my question using the literal comparison makes sense here (===), I just couldn't explain to myself why, heh. Thx!

Comment: This is not the (complete) reason. For example in JavaScript, non empty string also evaluate to `true`, but `true == 'X'` is `false`. It depends on what type conversion takes place. In general there is a difference between evaluation and type conversion. Now, I don't know where the comparison algorithm for PHP is defined, but the outcome is described in the second [comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: @FelixKling This is true, but who said anything about JavaScript?

Comment: It's just an example to show that only because something evaluates to `true`, it does not have to be `true`. But maybe I'm just making it more complicated than it is ;) It could very well be that in PHP the string is cast to a boolean value when compared with a boolean value and in this case there would be no difference between the evaluation value and the type conversion value... just thought it might be worth pointing out.

Comment: Follow up on my previous comment, this this indeed the case. The comparison is defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP's type juggling may have it's advantages, but in my opinion it leads to "dangerous" misunderstandings. Other examples that are not intuitiv would be:

```
'abc' == 0;
0 == null;
'' == null;
1 == '1y?z'
```

These are all considered true in PHP for various reasons. I always recommend to write your own function to check for equality, which works as you expect it (or do you have the whole PHP [type comparison matrix](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) in your mind?);

Comment: That's actually nice to show that `true == 'abc'` and `'abc' == 0` but `true != 0`...